# Can't record audio with Screen Capture API

Tags: javascript, screen-capture

So I'm trying to use the Screen Capture API to record audio and I have something like this:

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
  video: {
    frameRate: 1,
  },
  audio: {
    echoCancellation: { ideal: true },
    noiseSuppression: { ideal: true },
  },
});
```

but the resulting stream has only a video track and no audio. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: What browser are you using? Currently, this feature is [only available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API) on Chrome 74 and Edge 79.

Comment: check which constraints are available for you using navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()

Answer (score 1):

I was testing screen capture API, i needed, on browser, to select the option "Share audio", which is only available on some capture options, and it depends of the browser that you're using. In my tests, on Microsoft Edge, i can record audio on entire screen and edge tabs, on Chrome i can record only on chrome tabs.

Comment: I consider this a partial answer. I.e. accetable participation in the answering process while there is no full answer.